# cannot query array-like object returned from Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using node.js / express and mongoose (mongodb) and passport. I am having trouble getting to the key/value pairs of the returned array- like object.
user model:

```
{ 
 local : {
   email     : String,
   password  : String
},
 skills : {
  skill     : String,
  level     : Number
 }
}
```

I can add new skills to the user like this: Works exactly as intended

```
app.post( '/addskill', function ( req, res ) {
    var newskill = {skill : req.body.skill,  level : req.body.level};
    User.findByIdAndUpdate( req.user.id,
     { $push: { skills: newskill }}, 
     function (err, user ) {
      res.redirect('/profile');
    });
});
```

I can easily access the email and password strings in my ejs file like this:

```
<%= user.local.email %>
<%= user.local.password %>
```

When I query the db with

```
user.skills
```

I can get all the skills in this format:

```
[ { skill: 'qwe', level: 1 }, { skill: 'html', level: 1 }, { skill: 'python', level: 4 } ]
```

Again, exactly what I am looking for. What I want to do now is create a table listing the skills and levels.

None of the array methods seem to work
I tried in the ejs template file.

```
user.skills.forEach()  -- not working 'user' is null
user.forEach --  works to create a list of users.
user.skills[0].skill  -- not working
user.skills[i].skill -- in var loop, not working
```

here is the error message:

```
Object [ { skill: 'qwe', level: 1 }, { skill: 'html', level: 1 }, 
{ skill: 'python', level: 4 } ] has no method 'forEach' at eval ...
```

So my question really is: How can I access the key-value pairs in the this collection (array?)

Thanks!!

Comment: Shouldn't `skills` be defined as an array in your schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution here is to define an array in your mongoose model:

All I had to do is add [] to the 'skill' section:

```
{ 
 local : {
   email     : String,
   password  : String
},
 skills : [{
  skill     : String,
  level     : Number
 }]
}
```

now all the array methods work!!